# Oracle: removing time from datetime field

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a `TIMESTAMP(4)` column, what is the correct way to select only the date and ignore the time.

For example, a select on a timestamp field containing

```
22:07:2015:17:55:07
```

would return

```
22:07:2015:00:00:00
```

Thanks

Comment: Directly from the documentation: [TRUNC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm)

Answer (score 3):

```
select to_char(trunc(systimestamp),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
```